# Web page throws the error "<function> is not defined."

Tags: javascript, html, function

I copied a fully working web page to a new file on my website, but after written a new function and removed some HTML code the JS function won't get executed when you press one of the two buttons. It just throws me the error "BeginSort is not defined."

The web page is supposed to be used to sort text lines.

Here, have some code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Text sorting</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face { font-family: Candles; src: url('../font/Candles.ttf'), url('../font/Candles.eot'); }

        .style1
        {
            font-family: Candles;
            font-size: 44pt;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        .style2
        {
            font-family: Candles;
            font-size: 24pt;
            color: #FFFFFF;

        }
        .style3
        {
            font-family: Candles;
            font-size: 24pt;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        .textareastyle
        {
            width: 450px;
            height: 310px;
        }
        html
        { 
            background: url('../backgrounds/YellowFadingBackground.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function BeginSort(descend) {
            var textlines = [""];
                textlines = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "\n").split("\n");
            var sortedlist = "";
            switch(descend) {
                case 0:
                    textlines.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
                break;

                case 1:
                    textlines.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
                break:
            }

            for(var i=0; i<textlines.length; i++) {
                if(i < (textlines.length - 1)) { sortedlist += textlines + "\n"; } else { sortedlist += textlines; }
            }

            document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = sortedlist;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="style1" align="center">Text sorter<br>
        <span class="style2">Sort the text lines in ascending or descending order!</span>
    </p>
    <p align="center" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16pt">
        Text to sort:<br>
        <textarea class="textareastyle" id="TextBox1"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p class="style2" align="center">
        <input type="button" value="Ascending" onclick="javascript:BeginSort(0);">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Descending" onclick="javascript:BeginSort(1);">
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error is "BeginSort is not defined".  What this means is that there is in error somewhere in that function.  You need to make sure that everysingle line in that function is accessing something that actually exists.

Comment: Remove the "javascript" from the onclick: `onclick="BeginSort(0);"`

Comment: I added javascript to the onclick because I got the error in the first place. :)

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: your `switch` statement has a syntax error -- after `case 1:`, your `break` statement should be followed by `;` and not `:`

Comment: @Clark I know, jackJoe told me. I had misstyped that char. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent, jackJoe's answer wasn't displayed when I commented. glad you got it solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in line 54 of your script, you're missing a ";" (you have a ":" instead).

Correct code and tested (I had no errors):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Text sorting</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face { font-family: Candles; src: url('../font/Candles.ttf'), url('../font/Candles.eot'); }

        .style1
        {
            font-family: Candles;
            font-size: 44pt;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        .style2
        {
            font-family: Candles;
            font-size: 24pt;
            color: #FFFFFF;

        }
        .style3
        {
            font-family: Candles;
            font-size: 24pt;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
        .textareastyle
        {
            width: 450px;
            height: 310px;
        }
        html
        { 
            background: url('../backgrounds/YellowFadingBackground.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function BeginSort(descend) {
            var textlines = [""];
                textlines = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "\n").split("\n");
            var sortedlist = "";
            switch(descend) {
                case 0:
                    textlines.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
                break;

                case 1:
                    textlines.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
                break;
            }

            for(var i=0; i<textlines.length; i++) {
                if(i < (textlines.length - 1)) { sortedlist += textlines + "\n"; } else { sortedlist += textlines; }
            }

            document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = sortedlist;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="style1" align="center">Text sorter<br>
        <span class="style2">Sort the text lines in ascending or descending order!</span>
    </p>
    <p align="center" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16pt">
        Text to sort:<br>
        <textarea class="textareastyle" id="TextBox1"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p class="style2" align="center">
        <input type="button" value="Ascending" onclick="javascript:BeginSort(0);">&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Descending" onclick="javascript:BeginSort(1);">
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That did the trick. And I've been sitting here for hours trying to figure it out. The colon and semicolon are too similar in my text editor. Thanks! --I cannot accept this as the answer yet though, gotta wait 6 minutes.

Comment: @VisualVincent consider using a debugger (or dev tools), and look for any error it throws. Chrome has a good one, look for it :)

Comment: My webhost has a built in editor which I use. I like it better getting it online immediatelly. Though I like Visual Studio's debugger for apsx, but I doubt that will work with pure HTML without having to copy around the source.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks. What I meant was to check the console/dev tools in the browser itself, it tells you if something is not right. Chrome has a very nice developer tools (as does Safari and Firefox).

Comment: The built-in DOM console/explorer was what I used to recieve the error. :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, it's also good practice to surround any Javascript code with `CDATA` tags like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  doSomething();
//]]>
</script>
```

This helps avoid errors like this one, resulting from the browser trying to interpret your Javascript like it's HTML.